# Unexpected LineJoinStyle behavior when lines in path at 180 degrees

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm getting a clipped LineJoin in a UIBezierPath when one line comes back exactly over the previous line.  If I adjust the second line by one pixel, the LineJoin behaves as expected.  Here's the code:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path setLineWidth:10.0f];
[path setLineCapStyle:kCGLineCapRound];
[path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 100)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(150, 100)];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 120)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200, 120)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(150, 121)];
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
[path stroke];
```

Here's what's displayed:

[image]

Is this a bug?
If not, is there some way to get the top path LineJoin to be rounded? (without fudging the points)

This came up when I made a UIBezierPath from 'touch-input', and while scribbling around sometimes this happened.

Comment: Wow. Seems like a nasty bug.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  Please report this to Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Submitted to apple and also on open radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/12723863

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in iOS 7.
Open Radar also updated.